# How to rewrite method js in custom module magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, wysiwyg

I want to rewrite method `openVariableChooser` in variables js called somewhere in Editor magento. But i don't know how to do that without affect to other module

File variables location in Magento_Variable/variables.js

What i have done is define my custom js over original.

```
"paths": {
    "Magento_Variable/variables": "My_Extension/js/custom_variables"
},
```

Comment: You can override using theme inside Magento_Variable/web/js folder

Comment: How to do that in module

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using module like this,

Create file, **requirejs-config.js**

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Variable/variables": 'Vendor_Modulename/variables',
        }
    }
};
```

**Create app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/variables.js file**

run command, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

clear cache and browser cache.

Comment: have you worked this method?

Comment: Worked in my module but still affect to cms module. Cms not working  properly. Try to insert variable in cms i had to click twice to make it work